# PyCharm console keeps "Getting Documentation from Python Runtime"

Tags: pycharm

I'm working (with pandas) in a Python Console in PyCharm, and while I'm typing commands it keeps hanging for 10-20 seconds while "Getting Documentation from Python Runtime."  How do I prevent it from doing this?